# DomPdf not aligning text when a non default Font is added

Tags: php, fonts, dompdf, text-align

I'm trying to create a small application in which one of the modules is supposed to print the company badges, I have created a basic code only to test but the images are being centered however the text doesn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Carnets</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$html = 
'<table style="height: 506.5px; width: 319px;" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center"><img src="archivos\logo.jpg" alt="logoAig"/><br><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center"><img src="archivos\USUARIO.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt="usuario"/><br><br><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-family: aigfuturamed; font-size: 32; color: rgb(0,164,228);">NAME</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;"><br><br><span style="font-family: aigfuturamed; font-size: 24; color: rgb(0,164,228);">LASTNAME</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>';

function creaCarnet($html){
    // instantiate and use the dompdf class
    $html = '<html><body>'.$html.'</body></html>';
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper(array(0,0,319,506.5), 'portrait'); 

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    // Get the generated PDF file contents
    $pdf = $dompdf->output();

    // Output the generated PDF to Browser
    $dompdf->stream();
}

//echo $html;
creaCarnet($html);
?>



</body>
</html>
```

When showing the HTML on the website all the words are centered but when printing the PDF doesn't work at all. What am I missing here? The font I'm using is a special version of Futura, don't mind it if I use it with any other font or without choosing a font in particular the problem still shows.

The version for dompdf is: 0.6.2

New information regarding this issue, I started fresh, without all of the other test I had ran before and created a new file and it worked "great" on the count that it did aligned the text. However when I added the new font is the issue now, if I go and use any of the standard default fonts I don't have an issue but since the company policy requires to be with this special font when I go and select the font "aigfuturamed" that I created using the load_font.php that's when I have the issue.

This is the added information on the dompdf_font_family_cache.dist:

`'aigfuturamed' => 
  array (
    'normal' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'AIGFutura-Medium',
    'bold' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'AIGFutura-Medium',
    'italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'AIGFutura-Medium',
    'bold_italic' => DOMPDF_FONT_DIR . 'AIGFutura-Medium',
  ),`

This is the current result:
[Card incorrectly showing font to the left instead of center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqcrP.png)

And this is the result I want:
[And this is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkBd5.png)

Comment: Have you tried wkhtmltopdf?  It needs to be installed on the server, but is really nice to use.  As far as dompdf, I've used style text-algin:center in <td> before and it has centered the text with dompdf.  Not sure what is happening in your situation.

Comment: Doesn't work at all, as in the words are left-aligned? Or the words are off-center? Can you share a sample of the PDF output?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add pictures, I have added them now.